# how do you draw out a cube in blender by dragging with LMB

Tags: python, blender

i would like to be able to create a cube by clicking and dragging with the left mouse button rather than just have a cube be created with `'Shift+A'` `'M'` `'C'` and then need to edit the properties

however im not sure how to go about getting the mouse x and y location to place into the create cube function
`bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=2, calc_uvs=True, enter_editmode=True, align='WORLD', location=(mouse.x, mouse.y, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(0, 0, 0)`?

any help would be greatly appreciated!